# Factories with sinatra and rspec possible?

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra, sequel, factories

I wondered if anyone had any success with using any of the facorty testing tools out there with Sinatra, Sequel and RSpec?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at [Rstat.us](https://github.com/caleywoods/rstat.us) on Github. We're using Factory Girl with Sinatra. Although we are using MiniTest instead of RSpec. Maybe you can take something away from looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like [machinist](https://github.com/notahat/machinist) or [factory girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl)?

Yes, but what are you after specifically? Not really any different to setting up data using fixtures or using helpers in your code in practice.